# WebSocket not showing js alert

Tags: javascript, php, websocket

I have been advised that the solution in another SO post of mine might involve WebSocket. It just closes the connection instantly when used with my Url, but the javascript.info Url works fine. But why is that?

## console.log says:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://verlager.com/hello' failed:
```

```js
function sentry() {
  if ("WebSocket" in window) {
    console.log("WebSocket is supported by your Browser!");

    // Let us open a web socket
    
    // THIS WORKS:
    let socket = new WebSocket("wss://javascript.info/article/websocket/demo/hello");
    
    // But my server doesn't work! Why doesn't it work on my server?
    var ws = new WebSocket("wss://verlager.com/hello");

    ws.onopen = function() {
      // Web Socket is connected, send data using send()
      ws.send("Message to send");
      console.log("Message is sent...");
    };

    ws.onmessage = function (evt) { 
      var received_msg = evt.data;
      console.log("Message is received...");
    };

    ws.onclose = function() { 
      // websocket is closed.
      console.log("Connection is closed..."); 
    };
  } else {
    // The browser doesn't support WebSocket
    console.log("WebSocket NOT supported by your Browser!");
  }
}
sentry();
```

Comment: your need to provide backend code and apache config etc

Comment: My ISP is installing laravel websocket today.

Comment: The question should be updated to include the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: You should ensure that your websocket server is running fine and enter the correct url

Answer (score 0):

First, I've encountered an error with the exact same format, when I tried to connect to wss://localhost, which wasn't running.
Try specifying the port of your server, I'm not sure which one it assumes by default. Also make sure that your server is running secure websockets and it's dealing correctly with your path `/hello`.